# Change droppable image when dropped inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not good at jquery.. I want to change the droppable image when I drag and drop inside the droppable.. how do I change it? I need the droppable image to change when it is droppable inside the draoppable box. Please help!

**jsFiddle**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/xInfinityMing/9vmw4mtc/6/
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dragIcons">
  <img width="100px" height="100px" src="assets/img/gebiz.png">
  <img width="100px" height="100px" src="assets/img/b2b.png">
  <img width="100px" height="100px" src="assets/img/pitches.png">
  <img width="100px" height="100px" src="assets/img/creative.png">
</div>
<div id="briefcase">
  <div id="briefcase-droppable">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.draggable
{
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1.0;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: none !important;
  animation: pulse 0.4s alternate infinite;
}
.end-draggable
{
  animation: 0;
}
.dropped
{
  position: static !important;
  transition: none !important;
  animation: 0;
}
#dragIcons
{
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#briefcase
{
  height: 485px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  background: url("../../../assets/img/folder.png");
  background-position:
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}
#briefcase-open
{
  height: 485px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  background: url("../../../assets/img/folder-open.png");
  background-position:
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}
#briefcase-droppable
{
  border-style: solid;
  height: 285px;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 110px;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  100% {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

** JS: **

```
$(function () {
$("#dragIcons img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    refreshPositions: true,
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.removeClass("end-draggable");
        ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("end-draggable");
      ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
    }
});
$("#briefcase-droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($("#briefcase").length == 0) {
            $("#briefcase-droppable").html("");
        }
        ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
        $("#briefcase-droppable").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the `drop event` you can get the draggable element like this `ui.draggable` so to change your image source for example you should do

```
ui.draggable.attr('src','Your new source Here');
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/9vmw4mtc/8/

js:

```
$(function() {
  $("#dragIcons img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    refreshPositions: true,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.removeClass("end-draggable");
      ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("end-draggable");
      ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
    }
  });
  $("#briefcase-droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.attr('src','https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/double-up-arrow-angles_318-53141.png');
      if ($("#briefcase").length == 0) {
        $("#briefcase-droppable").html("");
      }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#briefcase-droppable").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

**Update:**

If you want to change the `background image` of the `droppable element` you also will make it in drop event but you will get the `droppable element` using `$(this)`

```
$(this).parent().css('background-image','your new background here');
```

Updated demo : https://jsfiddle.net/9vmw4mtc/9/

```
$(function() {
  $("#dragIcons img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    refreshPositions: true,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.removeClass("end-draggable");
      ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("end-draggable");
      ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
    }
  });
  $("#briefcase-droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().css('background-image','url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/yosemite-flat/512/Folder-icon.png")');
      if ($("#briefcase").length == 0) {
        $("#briefcase-droppable").html("");
      }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#briefcase-droppable").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I wanted to change is droppable image. the folder when drop inside the droppable. I don't want change the draggable image...

Comment: @YiMing look at the fiddle - this is exactly what you are looking for, and from your response, you don't seem to know how drag and drop works. Accept the answer. I'm giving it an upvote.

Comment: @YiMing I updated the answer and add another demo that change the droppable element background . check this : https://jsfiddle.net/9vmw4mtc/9/